# "FAILED" message on startup, but services running?

Tags: startup

When booting, I receive the following 2 messages:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Start NTP daemon.
See 'systemctl status ntp.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Cryptography Setup for sda7_crypt.
See 'systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@sda7_crypt.service' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Encrypted Volumes.
```

But NTP seems to be running after starting my computer, and my sda7_crypt volume does indeed mount.

```
$ systemctl status ntp.service
● ntp.service - LSB: Start NTP daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ntp; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-05-28 15:54:39 CDT; 1h 3min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 32060 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/ntp stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 32125 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ntp start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
           └─32138 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 117:125

May 28 15:54:42 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: Soliciting pool server 109.75.177.149
May 28 15:54:43 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: Soliciting pool server 104.236.236.18
May 28 15:54:43 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: Soliciting pool server 148.251.127.15
May 28 15:54:43 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: Soliciting pool server 85.254.217.3
May 28 15:54:43 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: Soliciting pool server 85.214.194.162
May 28 16:18:21 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: 81.88.24.155 local addr 192.168.0.25 
May 28 16:22:56 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: 85.214.194.162 local addr 192.168.0.2
May 28 16:26:28 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: 195.138.69.242 local addr 192.168.0.2
May 28 16:27:23 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: 144.76.202.253 local addr 192.168.0.2
May 28 16:28:36 Ubuntu ntpd[32138]: 148.251.127.15 local addr 192.168.0.2
```

So why does my computer say it failed?

Comment: this is a complete guess but I would assume that it tries to start those services ... they fail because something else they need isn't running yet then retry a second time but on the second attempt the items that they were dependent on are now running so they succeed.